How can I broadcast a STOMP messages to all RabbitMQ servers?
I'm working in a multiserver environment. It uses Spring WebSocket and RabbitMQ as an external broker for STOMP.
My JavaScript clients send messages to one single backend server through a balancer. It relays the message to RabbitMQ to reach all other clients listening to specific topic.
I need to handle a message from client to ALL active backend servers. How can I do it?
It is possible somehow to let all servers subscribe to STOMP topic like a JavaScript client does?
